# Used by custom attribute - IDE0051: Remove unused private member

Tags: c#, .net

The following code:

```
[CheckConstraint(Description = "Id must be greater than 0.")]
private bool CK_Id
{
    get { return Id > ZERO; }
}
```

will produce `IDE0051: Remove unused private member` warning in Visual Studio. The `CK_Id` is actually used by the framework because it has a custom `CheckConstraint` attribute. Is there any way we can do in `CheckConstraint` attribute so that this IDE0051 warning will be eliminated?

Edit:
I'm not alone: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34986. This issue is closed but not resolved.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0079 ?

Comment: `#pragma warning disable <...>` not desired?  And then enable it after that block.

Comment: `#pragma warning disable <...>` is not desired - it will be needed everywhere the custom attribute being used. The best way is to have some extension point in custom attribute implementation.

Comment: Best I can think of off-hand would be using `[SuppresMessage]` attribute.  But that's basically the same thing, just less verbose.  And unfortunately that class is sealed so you can't inherit from it either.

Comment: You're not alone.
When you add System.Runtime.Serialization.OnSerializing to a method, the warning is  not produced. 

When you switch that you a custom attribute, it is produced. Either there's a way to add code to an attribute to prevent this warning or there's custom code in the VS compiler.